# Problem with Figure

Tags: graphics, floats, fullwidth

If I do the following:

```
\begin{figure} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{steiner-output.jpg}
    \caption{Visualisation of connected brain regions using Steiner minimal tree.}
    \label{fig:vis1}
\end{figure}
```

I get something like:

[image]

But if I change the code to:

```
\begin{figure*} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{steiner-output.jpg}
    \caption{Visualisation of connected brain regions using Steiner minimal tree.}
    \label{fig:vis1}
\end{figure*}
```

The graphics **disappears** from the pdf. Can anyone tell me why and what am i doing wrong?

I can provide a link to an working example if needed.

---

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sa2u6gfdizidgs/problem.zip?dl=0) to a minimal example where you can see the problem. The latex file has the same graphics twice, once as `figure` and the second as `figure*`. You will see the first shows up but the second one doesn't.

---

Here is an link of the files of [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/3982468zxjkzh). This should remove the security concerns. Ones its solved, I can upload the exact part the code causing the problem which may be more achievable.

Comment: Are you sure it really disappeared, not just moved to the next page? If so, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/21344) is needed.

Comment: Please post your minimal working example here by editing your question. External links go stale; questions and answers posted here should be self-sufficient whenever possible so that they remain generally useful to all users interested in an issue.

Comment: Also, \columnwidth is slightly less than 0.5\textwidth.

Comment: @PaulGessler  - Yes, I am certain that it disappears. I have tried a lot of things but can't tell why its disappeared.

Comment: @Thinker as already mentioned, post your minimal example here on-site. External links go stale, and no offense, but I have no interest in downloading a 434 KB zip file from a stranger on the internet.

Comment: Downloading a zip from an untrusted source is, indeed, a Bad Idea and therefore something a lot of people will be reluctant to do. If you'd posted the code here, I'd have seen if I could help. As it is, there is still nothing to be done here.

Comment: Its hard for me to do that since there are multiple fils and not only the tex code. I am not sure if its one of the other files causing the problem hence the issue.

Ok let me post an online copy using online text editor. Hopefully that satisfies your request.

I have just added a link on overleaf

Comment: I've found that many times when working with large files, and trying to reduce my code for Tex.se, that very process has lead me to understand why my code did not work. I would really suggest trying as far as possible to do so.

Comment: The problem appears to be the `changebar` package, see the linked question for details. By deleting all irrelevant stuff and removing packages one after the other, you can easily find out what broke your code.